# Can you Super Swim on the Gamecube Version of wind waker on the Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, nintendo-gamecube, zelda-wind-waker

What I'm asking is that I could use storage on the gamecube when I play the game. But it seems to be more difficult when  play it on the Wii. On a GameCube disc. Since Super swimming is fun, Is it possible when I play the GameCube disc of Wind Waker that I can use storage and in turn, Super Swim?

Comment: This does seem very confusing but hang on to what it says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**. Gamecube games perform exactly the same on the Wii as they do on the Gamecube. Playing games on the Wii has no impact on what glitches are possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot I thought something was wrong considering I was trying more times that usual

Comment: Maybe not exactly, as the hardware must be slightly different? But for most intents and purposes, yes.[/pedantic]